# NestJS run worker in a separate process

Tags: nestjs, worker

I am implementing NestJS worker, [queues](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/queues), using [Bull](https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull).

According to the [documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/queues), both the worker and the server (will) run in a same "process", but I want to run the worker in a separate process, so as to **not** block the main event loop.

I think it's called "running a task in a separate binary" or something else.

Anyway, I tried googling it, went through the documentation of NestJS, but couldn't find something similar.

++
In other words:

I have a main project (my current), and I want to create the worker in a separate process (standalone application) and want to connect both my current main project and worker. And I can't really find it in the documentation.

In which module should I instantiate my Bull's instance? I am assuming I'll keep my `producer` in my main module and `consumer` in my worker module.

How can I do so?

Please note, by "separate process", I do not mean running a specific task in a separate process, as defined in Bull's [documentation](https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull#separate-processes).
I want to deploy the whole worker module in a separate process or whatever the term should be used.

++
[Extra, if possible]

Before running my server and worker, I also want to check whether my worker (bull instance) is successfully connected to my Redis server. I couldn't find anything on the Bull's documentation... do you think there is a good workaround for that?

Comment: You could always separate your worker in a stand-alone app, I think that’s what you mean by “separate binary” in this context.

Comment: “ I couldn't find anything on the Bull's documentation...”, are you sure? What about https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull#separate-processes

Comment: check my answer, it’s the same thing the example shown just isn’t the best.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Goal: Horizontal Scaling ✅

While the [answer provided by Isolated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70230778/8164116) should work, I didn't want to run a whole new project and import my modules as he suggested. So after some more R&D, I've figured out a (better) way to do so.

Just as we have our `index.ts` or `main.ts` file for our "parent" project, in the same dir (doesn't have to be), create a `worker.ts` and `worker.module.ts`.

In the `worker.module.ts`, make sure you register your **Bull** module **again** [`BullModule.forRoot({})`] and include all the imports that you'd need for your consumer.

In the `providers`, you should add our `consumers` and you'll be good to go.

The `worker.ts` would look like this (nothing fancy):

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { NestExpressApplication } from '@nestjs/platform-express';
import { WINSTON_MODULE_NEST_PROVIDER } from 'nest-winston';
import { WorkerModule } from './worker/worker.module';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create<NestExpressApplication>(WorkerModule);
  app.useLogger(app.get(WINSTON_MODULE_NEST_PROVIDER));
  process.env.WORKER_HTTP_PORT = process.env.WORKER_HTTP_PORT ?? '4001';
  await app.listen(process.env.WORKER_HTTP_PORT);
  console.debug(`Worker is running on ${await app.getUrl()}`);
}
bootstrap();
```

Your `nest-cli.json` should like something like this

```
{
  "collection": "@nestjs/schematics",
  "sourceRoot": "src",
  "entryFile": "main",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "assets": ["**/*.graphql"],
    "watchAssets": true
  }
}
```

and create a new `nest-cli-worker.json`

```
{
    "collection": "@nestjs/schematics",
    "sourceRoot": "src",
    "entryFile": "worker",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "watchAssets": true
    }
}
```

Now, the question is, how to run it?

I am using `yarn` commands to start my server (defining them in `package.json`)

To `start` my `server`, I'd

```
"start:dev": "yarn nest start --watch -e 'node -r dotenv/config -r source-map-support/register'"
```

or

```
"start:prod": "node -r dotenv/config -r ./tsconfig-paths-bootstrap.js dist/src/main.js"
```

and to **`start`** my **`worker`**, I'd run the following command(s) in **another** (terminal) shell...

> Dev

```
"worker:start:dev": "yarn nest start --config nest-cli-worker.json --watch -e 'node -r dotenv/config -r source-map-support/register'"
```

or

> Prod

```
"worker:start:prod": "node -r dotenv/config -r ./tsconfig-paths-bootstrap.js dist/src/worker.js"
```

P.S You don't necessarily have to add `dotenv/config`.

**Bonus:**

> If you want to run your server(s) in `docker`

Here's my `docker-compose.yaml` file

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  main:
    container_name: my-server
    image: xxx.amazonaws.com/xx/xxx:${CONTAINER_IMAGE_TAG:-latest}
    ports:
      - 80:80
    command: node -r dotenv/config -r ./tsconfig-paths-bootstrap.js dist/src/main.js #My `prod` command for main server
    volumes:
      - xxx
    links:
      - xxx
    environment:
      xxx
    # .env is generated by Elastic Beanstalk, don't provide one
    env_file:
      - .env
  worker:
    container_name: worker-server #YOUR WORER
    image: xxx.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/xxx:${CONTAINER_IMAGE_TAG:-latest}
    ports:
      - 90:90
    links:
      - xxx
    command: node -r dotenv/config -r ./tsconfig-paths-bootstrap.js dist/src/worker.js  #prod command for Worker
    volumes:
      - xxx
    environment:
      xxx
    # .env is generated by Elastic Beanstalk, don't provide one
    env_file:
      - .env
```

Comment: Hi ! Are you happy with this approach ? Using Bull / Redis and your worker ?
Have you tried running multiple instances of your app AND your worker ?

Comment: Hey, so far it's getting the job done... but haven't tried running *multiple* instances of runner. I think I'll just have to spawn it in another port and it should be fine. Been running my worker on Staging like this for 15 days and no complaints till now!

Comment: So are you already running multiple of the app?

Comment: "Multiple of the app?" I don't follow...

Comment: Super helpful @DakshGargas, thank you!

Comment: Thank you!!! This is the way. Especially if you want to horizontally scale your processes by adding more Docker containers as needed.

Answer (score 28):

You *can* use that documentation to implement the entire worker. If you **use Nest.js in standalone mode** you can just have Processor(s) and Process(es).

This is documented [here](https://docs.nestjs.com/standalone-applications). “Separate binary” isn’t a question either. A binary is the product of compilation, Node.js isn’t compiled so you’ll need a separate **application**.

You don’t need a workaround for anything, this is literally the nature of Bull and optionally Nest.js.

Sometimes you’ll need to adapt examples in docs to fit your needs, this can take some time to learn.

#### Terminology

I think there's some confusion with terminology so in this post assume that:

1. A `process` is what your `application` runs inside (if you look in your OS process manager it should be `node`).
2. A `application` is **one** Node.js project that runs in a separate `process`.
3. A `worker` is an `application` that is **only focused with processing Queue jobs**.
4. `Queue` and `Job` is terminology of Bull.
5. `Processor` and `Process` is terminology of Nest.js `@nestjs/bull`

#### Solution

Here is how you create an **application** with a **worker** running in separate processes. After following these instructions, you should see two processes running your process manager.

Create a new Nest.js application that we'll use for your `worker`:

```sh
nest new my-worker
```

Open `src/main.ts` and replace everything in `bootstrap` function with:

```
const app = await NestFactory.createApplicationContext(AppModule);
```

Install `Bull` and the Nest.js implementation with:

```sh
yarn add @nestjs/bull bull
```

Open `src/app.module.ts` and remove `AppController` from `controllers`, and add `BullModule.registerQueue` to imports (from `@nestjs/bull`.

Your `src/app.module.ts` should now look like:

```js
// app.module.ts
// ... imports
@Module({
  imports: [
    BullModule.registerQueue({
      name: 'my-queue',
      redis: {
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 6379,
      },
    }),
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Create a new file: `app.processor.ts` in `src` directory:

```js
// app.processor.ts
// ... imports
@Processor('my-queue')
export class AppConsumer {
    @Process('namedjob')
    async processNamedJob(job: Job<any>): Promise<any> {
        // do something with job and job.data
    }
}
```

And you're done for the `worker` side of things. Now all you need to do is in your `application` (main project), update your `AppModule` to include `BullModule.registerQueue` (like above) and inject it:

```js
export class MyService {
  constructor(@InjectQueue('my-queue') private queue: Queue) {}
}
```

And then use `this.queue.add('namedJob', data);`

Try above and if you get stuck, create a repository on Github and I'll get you on the right track.

#### Reference

1. https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull#separate-processes
2. https://docs.nestjs.com/standalone-applications

Comment: Yeah, I saw this, but couldn't figure out how can I use it in my project.
I have a main project ( my current), and I want to create the worker in a separate process (standlone application) and want to connect both my current main project and worker. And I can't really find it in the documentation.

Comment: And in which module should I instantiate my Bull's instance? I am assuming I'll keep my `producer` in my main module and `consumer` in my worker module.

Comment: @DakshGargas I updated my answer. You shouldn't have separate modules, you should have two separate projects/apps. Take a look and let me know if I can help any further but hopefully that should cover it.

Comment: I'm doing the same thing, but this won't spawn my worker as a separate `application`. But maybe I am off on one step... when you asked me to do `nest new my-worker`... is this a whole new project? If so, how should I connect it with my current project? Also, my `consumer` will be using multiple modules from my current project.

Comment: @DarshGargas yes an entirely new projects. The problem with this is you’ll need to either consume those modules through an API or some other means, or duplicate them from your main project into your worker. However, with this approach you gain a cleaner separation plus achieve the separate process. You need not worry about connecting the two as this happens over Redis providing you connect both projects to the same Redis.

Comment: Hey, I've added a solution, might wanna check it out.
Thanks for your help... it was a nice starting point. And thank you for clearing out my doubts and providing detailed definitions :)